# getting error accessing gmongo from gremlin

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, gremlin

I am getting the following error while trying to import `gmongo` :

```
org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.CommandException: Invalid import definition: 'import com.gmongo.GMongo'; reason: startup failed:
script14697532165911332202368.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.gmongo.GMongo
```

How can I assure than my gremlin runs from `neo4j` ?

Comment: in what context are you doing this? in the Gremlin Console? and what version of gremlin are you using?

Comment: I want to integrate mongodb with neo4j. I am using neo4j-3.0.3, gremlin version 2.6.0 and neo4j-gremlin-plugin-tp3-2.3.1

Comment: i'm sorry but that doesn't explain your problem well enough for me to answer. what does integrating mongo with neo4j mean? are you using the Gremlin Console? are you using Maven to build a project? I think you have to provide more detail about how you are getting the above error in your question. my guess is that you are missing the Gmongo jar somehow, but without more context i'm not sure how to advise you to fix that problem.

Comment: Ok..let me tell you the scenario. I have a project which use mongoDB as database. My project is maven dependent. Now I wanna connect this mongoDb with neo4j using gremlin. what should be the steps I need to follow...Please guide me

Comment: your pom.xml should contain dependencies for gmongo, and gremlin-neo4j - is that present? i'm somewhat surprised by your use of maven given the error which is groovy (maybe even console) based - i'm not clear on what that has to do with maven.